# how to use globalThis polyfill in a NextJS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, polyfills

I'm using a popular react component library Mantine and it seems like it's components are having issues with older iOS versions as it says:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis

I know there's some polyfills out there but I cannot seem to figure out how to apply it to my NextJS project so that it applies to the externallibraries i'm using as well

https://www.npmjs.com/package/globalthis

All the examples I'm seeing online are if you're using globalThis in your own code, but in my situation it's a library that's using it.

thank you in advance

Comment: Just import and run the polyfill before importing and running the external library. There shouldn't be any difference otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the import to your root custom `App` or `_app.tsx` file.

See https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/supported-browsers#custom-polyfills

Also see this comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/20992#discussioncomment-275748

```
import 'globalthis/polyfill';
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34717059)